# In vtree: How to sort each node in descending order vs. alphabetical

Tags: r, vtree

By now, if we do this:

```
library(vtree)

vtree(mtcars, "cyl am",
      sameline = TRUE, 
      follow=list(cyl="4"))
```

**we get this:**
[image]

I would like to **sort in descending order without manipulating the data**.
Is this possible?

**Desired output:**

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't see a way of doing this in the `vtree` function, but you can swap the nodes in the output if that is any use to you?

```r
vt <- vtree(mtcars, "cyl am",
            sameline = TRUE, 
            follow = list(cyl = "4"))

str2 <- str <- strsplit(vt$x$diagram, "\n")[[1]]

node5 <- grep("^Node_5", str)
node6 <- grep("^Node_6", str)

str2[node5] <- sub("Node_6", "Node_5", str[node6])
str2[node6] <- sub("Node_5", "Node_6", str[node5])

vt$x$diagram <- paste(str2, collapse = "\n")

vt
```

[image]